# d3.js - area chart vertical overflow if y.domain doesn't start at 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I limit the contents of an area chart to stay inside the area determined by the two axes?

Here's the situation. If I set the vertical domain to be between 0 and the maximum of my data set, I don't have a problem:

```
y.domain([0, 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
```

[image: correct]

However, sometimes I can't start from 0. When I need to start from the smallest number in the data set, the problem emerges:

```
y.domain([0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
```

[image: incorrect]

As you see, the blue area of the chart flows over the bottom horizontal axis, and that's just ugly and messy. I could switch to a line chart to avoid this problem, but I'd much rather keep an area chart and resolve the issue. Any solutions?

EDIT This is the full code I'm using. If the `full` parameter is `true`, then the chart starts at 0. If not, then it starts at the data minimum.

```
function create_area_chart(data, full){
    var svg = d3.select(".chart-holder").append("svg").attr("width","800").attr("height", "400")
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
        bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var area = d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    if(full)
        y.domain([0, 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    else
        y.domain([0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    area.y0(y(0));

    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("d", area);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Price ($)");

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
}
```

Comment: How do you call your axis?

Comment: @ArnaudStephan You're gonna have to elaborate on that, I don't know what you're asking me.

Comment: How do you append your vertical and horizontal axis on your `.chart-holder`?

edit : well I need coffee, I hadn't seen that your code was longer and that I had to scroll to see the end

Comment: @ArnaudStephan Oh, you mean call(d3.axisBottom) etc. I got confused for a moment too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `floor` for the area chart by changing `y0`

```
if(full){
    y.domain([0, 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    area.y0(y(0));
} else {
    y.domain([0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 1.1*d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    area.y0(y(0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; })));
}
```

see the docs: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#areas

**EDIT**

## Reproducing the Problem

Consider this area [chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195) which OP's code is adapted from.

I run the code in the example and get the following plot:

[image]

Everything is as expected. The `y domain` and `y0` are set as follows:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
area.y0(y(0));
```

Now, if I change the `y domain` to:

```
y.domain([
    0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.close; }),
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })
]);
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

We get the overflow, but if I now change the `y0()` to match the new `y domain` to:

```
area.y0(y(0.91*d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.close; })));
```

which plots:

[image]

The overflow has now been corrected.

Comment: It really should. Are you setting `area.y0(y(0));` any where else apart from inside the if statement?

Comment: You're right. I had some code double-pasted and it left the area.y0 bit in there after I set it according to what you said. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I just edited my answer to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from the range of your scales.

Maybe try with

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height-margin.bottom, margin.top]);
```

edit : it's probably not what's wrong with your code though, since you define `height` minus the two margins already. Sorry, best of luck !

Comment: No, this just moves the whole y-axis up and away from the x-axis. Thanks for trying though.